# Python Array slicing. [:,:]

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have this code that I am looking over and commenting (I made some improvements to it but I have not really looked in-depth at the math and creation part)

Declaration :

```
percentile = ((nextImage - BaselineMin) / (BaselineMax - BaselineMin)) * 100
```

Where nextImage, BaselineMin and BaselineMax are all 720x600 numpy arrays.

Essentially, out of this, I should get another 720x600 Numpy arry

Calling

```
percentile[:, :][percentile[:, :] == 0] = -999
```

I am interested to know what each part does. Me and a co-worker looked at it and tried to replicate it with a sample 2x2 and 3x3 array and all we got is []. Alternatively, we got a flattened list, but could not replicate it.

This has to do with array slicing, but i've never seen anything like this. I have taken a look at the other questions around here, but none of them have anything like this.

Comment: FYI: You can simplify that to `percentile[percentile == 0] = -999`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cutting the operation

### first part

`percentile[:, :] == 0` or just `percentile == 0` will give a boolean numpy array of 720x600, True where the value==0 otherwise False.

### second part

`percentile[percentile == 0]` gives the values that meet the condition, so all 0 value in the array.

### third and last part

`percentile[percentile == 0] = -999`, update the zero values by -999.

## An example

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.rand(4, 4)
A[A >= 0.5] = 1
```

The samples that are >= to 0.5 will be replaced by 1 in this array of random samples.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this explanation. I figured this was just an over-complicated thing that should have been much easier. I will re-write it for readability.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, the line of code in question reads like this:

"Set anything in `percentile` that is 0 to -999".

The first part `percentile[:,:]` just refers to every element in `percentile`. I'm fairly sure you wouldn't need the array slicing here, just replacing with `percentile`.

The index on `percentile`, `percentile[:,:] == 0` then, should become a matrix of all booleans, `True` if the corresponding element in `percentile` is 0 and `False` otherwise.  Again, the array slicing `percentile[:,:]` is not necessary.

Indexing an array like this is called masking, and the matrix of booleans is called a mask.  Essentially the mask selects the items of the indexed array where the mask is `True` so you can do something with them; here they are being set to -999.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

That line of code sets every element in "percentile" that has a value of 0 to -999.

Here is a simple 2 by 2 example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([[1,2],[0,4]])
>>> arr
array([[1, 2],
       [0, 4]])
>>> arr[:,:][arr[:,:] == 0] = -999
>>> arr
array([[   1,    2],
       [-999,    4]])
```

As [Warren Wessecker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217358/warren-weckesser) mentions, that can be simplified. Consider the following:

```
>>> arr = np.array([[1,2],[0,4]])
>>> arr
array([[1, 2],
       [0, 4]])
>>> arr[arr == 0] = -999
>>> arr
array([[   1,    2],
       [-999,    4]])
```